# Using pygame features in Tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, pygame

I'd like to use some features from pygame (sprite graphics) in my GUI I made in Tkinter. I know of OcempGUI, but I'd prefer to stick to Tkinter, just use some modules from pygame. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291274/is-there-anything-i-need-aware-of-using-tkinter-and-pygame-together) is similar but not quite the same. Is this possible at all? What are potential problems (event loop)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works on Linux. If you're lucky, it might work on other operating systems as well.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import os

w, h = 500, 200

# Add a couple widgets. We're going to put pygame in `embed`.
root = tk.Tk()
embed = tk.Frame(root, width=w, height=h)
embed.pack()
text = tk.Button(root, text='Blah.')
text.pack()

# Tell pygame's SDL window which window ID to use    
os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())

# The wxPython wiki says you might need the following line on Windows
# (http://wiki.wxpython.org/IntegratingPyGame).
#os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'

# Show the window so it's assigned an ID.
root.update()

# Usual pygame initialization
import pygame as pg
pg.display.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((w,h))

pos = 0
while 1:
    # Do some pygame stuff
    screen.fill(pg.Color(0,0,0))
    pos = (pos + 1) % screen.get_width()
    pg.draw.circle(screen, pg.Color(255,255,255), (pos,100), 30)

    # Update the pygame display
    pg.display.flip()

    # Update the Tk display
    root.update()
```

Comment: Just tried this for windows, and it appears to work fine (without the line of code you have commented out)