# Widgets not displaying when combining tkinter and pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, pygame

I am making a music player application using both tkinter and pygame. I found online some ways to implement these two modules (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2012-September/091417.html, [Using pygame features in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584272/using-pygame-features-in-tkinter)), but my buttons are not visible. The pygame screen shows up fine, but I cannot get the buttons to show up.

Here is shortened version of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as tk2
import os
import pygame

playlist = ['song1.mp3', 'song2.mp3', 'song3.mp3', 'song4.mp3']

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)

        #create widgets
        self.playlistbox = Listbox(self, selectmode = SINGLE) #listbox
        for song in playlist:
            self.playlistbox.insert(END, song)
        self.playlistbox.grid(row = 1)
        self.playButton = Button(self, text = 'Play', command = self.play)  #button
        self.playButton.grid(row=1, column = 1)

        #pygame init
        embed = tk.Frame(root, width = 200 , height = 200)
        embed.pack()
        embed.pack(side = LEFT)
        os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
        os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
        pygame.display.init() 
        windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((200,100))
        pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

    def play(self):   #play song function
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        selectedSongs = self.playlistbox.curselection()
        pygame.mixer.music.load(self.playlistbox.get(0))
        pygame.mixer.music.play(0, 0.0)

root = Tk()
root.title('Text Editor')
root.geometry('700x600')
app = Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Amr Ayman's answer below is probably good advice, but if you are wondering your problem is that you forgot to include a `self.pack()` (not the embedded frame but the main tkinter frame) right after you initialize the listbox and buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is **really** an overkill ..
I coded a music player using the *exact same things* you're using here .. python, pygame and tkinter ..

You won't need initializing pygame's display module, becuase believe me, you don't need it ..
I'll tell you what I did ..

> I used pygame's music module using the Sound class to play the tracks ..
>   I created a class called **SoundPanel** which inherits from the Frame class to group: a volume scale, a play/stop checkbutton, and a label to view the first 23 letters of the track name and add some dots if the track name is larger than that ..
>   And to make that usable, I added an open file(s) button to add track(s) (with a file dialog using tkinter) to the view (i.e. Create a new SoundPanel object that plays the track) and a open folder button to add all files with a certain extension (defined by the user using a dialog containing a text box) to the view ..

I don't think you need any more than that ..
I don't say you have to mimic my solution but I think yours is too complicated ..
By the way, the widgets aren't displaying because you have to pack the frame when you're done creating the object ..

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am using pygame's display module because I plan on doing some graphics/design work on the application, but you're right it's overkill to use it just for audio.