# Move frameless pygame window?

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

my question is: how to **move a window** (aka display/video window) that has been **set to NOFRAME**?

```
import os
import pygame


window = pygame.display.set_mode((480,480), NOFRAME)
```

i've found that you can specify a SDL variable with the initial location of the window if you do it before initializing pygame like so:

```
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (x, y)
pygame.init()
```

but how can you change **x** and **y** while the app is running, for example, by dragging the window around with the mouse?

i've found solutions for Tkinter, Qt, Pyside, wm, but not for a pygame application.

Comment: You can embed Pygame in Tkinter.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi would i be able to call Tkinter functions when a pygame event occurs? for example, double the window's width when user clicks a sertain pygame.sprite?

Comment: I believe so, why not?

Comment: because I'm a total begginer, thanks btw.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584272/using-pygame-features-in-tkinter) for embedding help.

Comment: ty, that's gonna be helpful.