# PYgame and TKinter for Android

Tags: tkinter, pygame

I am building an app for android with PGS4A. I am using pygame but in pygame I want a scroll down window to show the instructions for my game and I want to use TKINTER for that.

Is is OK to use tkinter with pygame?
Will it work on android if I use tkinter as well along with pygame subset for android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Acording to an answer on this question: [Is there anything I need aware of using Tkinter and pygame together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291274/is-there-anything-i-need-aware-of-using-tkinter-and-pygame-together) it is apparently not so simple. Maybe read that question then try out a bit of Pygame and tkinter together. As for PGS4A I don't have any experience myself.