# Unexpected error while using PyGame audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pygame

I'm trying to write a script that plays audio files in background on loop. The audio to play is chosen randomly in a list of audio files.

I tried to do this: http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part3/

And wrote:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import pygame

_songs = ['audio1.ogg', 'audio2.ogg', 'audio3.ogg']
pygame.mixer.init()

_currently_playing_song = None

SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)


next_song = random.choice(_songs)
while next_song == _currently_playing_song:
        next_song = random.choice(_songs)
_currently_playing_song = next_song
pygame.mixer.music.load(next_song)
pygame.mixer.music.play()

while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == SONG_END:
                        pygame.mixer.music.load(next_song)
                        pygame.mixer.music.play()  
tk = Tk()
photo = PhotoImage(file="image.GIF")


image_label=Label(tk, image=photo)
image_label.grid(row=0, column=2)

tk.mainloop()
```

But I get this error:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

Is there a way to solve this or use pygame using tkinter instead than pygame video system?

Comment: Never tried mixing Tk with pygame.  Both are used to present a GUI and handle events.  I would think they would conflict unless you are very careful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `pygame.init()`. This will initialize the video system, which is required for the use of `pygame.event`. It is good practice to call at the beginning of every program that uses pygame. See the pygame event documentation [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) for more information.

Hope this helped.

EDIT:

As @cmd mentioned The program won't run correctly because you are using both Tkinter and pygame which have conflicting loops. A possible solution is to switch to using only one or the other and not both. See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8291274/is-there-anything-i-need-aware-of-using-tkinter-and-pygame-together) for more info.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't work. If I add pygame.init() after import pygame, when i run int, a Python shell appears, but nothing happens.

Comment: Is there an error that appears, or something doesn't happen that is supposed to happen?

Comment: A window with an image, with music playing in background should appear. But only an empty shell appears.