# Mac and Windows compatible GUI for Python, which is easy to install and works with pygame?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, portability, pygame

I have made a program that finds and measures the radius of yeast colonies in images.  It uses pygame for pixel access and graphical display of the images.

The next step is to make it "user friendly" so that the non-programmers in my university bio lab can use it.  Pygame lacks scroll bars, text fields, "open file" dialogues, etc., which I will need.  I have heard that it's a nightmare trying to mix pygame and Tkinter.  What can I use?

An additional requirement is that I want the set up of Python and all necessary modules to be easy to do on Windows and Mac, which is why I'm not using something like PIL, which must be set up from source on Mac. pygame seems to be easy to set up on Mac, and there's a windows .exe as well.  I want people to be able to download and run this program as simply as possible on their own laptops without my help.

If there is no easy way to make some kind of GUI module run alongside pygame, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to export my pygame Image, or list of pixels, or whatever, to be shown on a GUI?  Can I somehow make and manipulate a pygame Image without opening a window?  Or are there GUIs which allow pixel access (i.e., set_at() and get_at() ?)

I greatly appreciate your suggestions and advice!  I'm really stumped, and frustrated that I've gotten this program to work perfectly--except for the fact that no one but me can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fear not! [Other people have had the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142912/whats-the-best-way-to-add-a-gui-to-a-pygame-application) and have been helped.

Also, here are few useful links. These are GUI toolkits for PyGame [GooeyPy](http://www.pygame.org/projects/9/393/), [Mike's Simple GUI](http://www.pygame.org/projects/9/476/), [OcempGUI](http://www.pygame.org/projects/9/125/) and a [whole lot](http://www.pygame.org/tags/gui) more.

[PGU](http://www.pygame.org/project/108/) I think is one of the popular libraries that most game developers use and it seems to be reasonably well maintained.